# python - meta class, base constructor does not get called

Tags: python

I have created a meta-class which overrides the default **init** function in order to add a private variable.

The problem is that the **init** function of the base class doesn't get called if I don't explicitly call it myself.

Look at the example below

```
class Base(object):                           
    def __init__(self, x, y):                 
        self._xvar = x                        
        self._yvar = y                        
        print("THIS IS THE CONSTRUCTOR", x, y)


class Derived(Base):                          
    pass 


def main():                   
    derived = Derived(11, 20)
```

This will print

> THIS IS THE CONSTRUCTOR 11 20

even though the derived class never calls

```
super().__init__(x, y)
```

This is my metaclass:

```
class MetaTemplateContent(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, base, dct):
        # This is the original init function
        orig_init = dct.get("__init__")

        # this variable will hold all the functions that has a decorator 
        # If the function name is _content_wrapper it will handle static methods as well
        decorators = []
        for _, value in dct.items():
            if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
                if value.__name__ == "_content_wrapper":
                    decorators.append(value)
            elif isinstance(value, staticmethod):
                function = value.__func__
                if function.__name__ == "_content_wrapper":
                    decorators.append(function)

        # This is our wrapper init function which will act as a stub
        def init_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if orig_init:
                orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

            # This is the local variable I want to add to each instance
            # and fill it with all the functions that has the decorator
            self._callbacks = getattr(self, "_callbacks", [])
            self._callbacks.extend(decorators)

        # replace the original init with our stub
        dct["__init__"] = init_wrapper
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, base, dct)
```

If I were to rewrite our base class to this:

```
class Base(object, metaclass=MetaTemplateContent):
    def __init__(self, x, y):                     
        self._xvar = x                            
        self._yvar = y                            
        print("THIS IS THE CONSTRUCTOR", x, y)    


class Derived(Base):                              
    pass


def main():                  
    derived = Derived(11, 20)
```

Nothing will be printed because the base constructor never gets called.

Adding super().**init**(x, y) to the derived constructor however will do the trick:

```
class Derived(Base):          
    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        super().__init__(x, y)
```

But this is redundant and I know that I have missed something important here.
Why doesn't the base class constructor gets called?

This is python 3.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base class method is called in two cases:

1. You explicitly call it
2. The subclass does not define (i.e., override) the method

Without your metaclass, situation 2 applies.  As you already noted, your metaclass creates an `__init__` for each class that uses that metaclass.  So with your metaclass, situation 2 no longer applies, and the base class constructor is not called.

In other words, if a class defines `__init__`, it has to call the base class version explicitly if it wants it.  Your metaclass makes it so every class defines `__init__`, so if you want the base `__init__` to be called you have to call it explicitly.

You could modify your metaclass so that the init wrapper calls the superclass version only if there is no `orig_init`.  To do this, the init wrapper needs access to the class, so you need to swap things around so that you patch in the init wrapper *after* creating the class:

```
class MetaTemplateContent(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, base, dct):
        # This is the original init function
        orig_init = dct.get("__init__")

        # this variable will hold all the functions that has a decorator 
        # If the function name is _content_wrapper it will handle static methods as well
        decorators = []
        for _, value in dct.items():
            if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType):
                if value.__name__ == "_content_wrapper":
                    decorators.append(value)
            elif isinstance(value, staticmethod):
                function = value.__func__
                if function.__name__ == "_content_wrapper":
                    decorators.append(function)

        # make the class first
        cls = type.__new__(mcs, name, base, dct)

        # This is our wrapper init function which will act as a stub
        def init_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if orig_init:
                orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                super(cls, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            # This is the local variable I want to add to each instance
            # and fill it with all the functions that has the decorator
            self._callbacks = getattr(self, "_callbacks", [])
            self._callbacks.extend(decorators)

        # replace the original init with our stub
        cls.__init__ = init_wrapper
        return cls
```